# Create a new touch effect in a React Native button

Tags: react-native

React Native seems to come with a few built in effects for "touchable" views, such as TouchableOpacity, TouchableNativeFeedback etc. but none of them fit my use case.

Is there an obvious way to change the styles on a button as it's depressed (change the background color or enlarge the button using transform:scale etc.)? Obviously I'd want it to revert to the default styles when the user stops holding the button.

Comment: You can use Animated to create your own view and implement custom styles like varying opacity, color etc.. or implement custom dope animations...

Comment: I realise I could kick off some sort of animation when the button is pressed but I want the styles that it transitions to to stay as long as the user is holding the button down, then animate back to their original values when the user lets go.

Comment: yes you can do that using on TouchableWithoutFeedback there are props like onPressIn, onPressOut Refer https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback

Comment: https://github.com/noddy1996/react-native-touch-ripple try this